# How to write a burn function in smart contract for NFT?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, nft

I am learning how to write a smart contract for NFT collections and the following is the example function given by the tutorial I read:

```
    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal virtual override {
        super._burn(tokenId);
        if (bytes(_tokenURIs[tokenId]).length != 0) {
            delete _tokenURIs[tokenId];
        }
    }
```

I recognise that this function will not remove the token from the blockchain entirely. Instead, it will remove the URI of the token (regardless of who owns it). As a result, the token will still in the collection and be displayed on trading platforms, but the metadata will be gone (but it may take time to be in effect as platforms are not refreshing metadata frequently).

I wonder if this is the right practice for burn function. It would be greatly helpful for me if someone can provide me an example of how burn function is achieved on other NFT smart contracts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the easiest way to add `burn` function to an NFT.

- GO to [Openzepplin Wizard](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/wizard)
- Click `ERC721`
- Give your token a name and symbol.
- Click on `mintable` and `burnable`, and you would get `mintable` and `burnable` NFT token contract.

Here is a sample:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC721, ERC721Burnable, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC721("MyToken", "MTK") {}

    function safeMint(address to, uint256 tokenId) public onlyOwner {
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
    }
}
```

The corresponding OZ wizard interface would look like this:

[image]

You would get the following `public burn` function:

[image]

From [Openzepplin ERC721 burnable contract](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.7.2/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Burnable.sol)

## Update

You can make the contract both `enumarable` and `burnable`:
[image]

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721Burnable, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC721("MyToken", "MTK") {}

    function safeMint(address to, uint256 tokenId) public onlyOwner {
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
        internal
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
}
```

Comment: So that's a built-in function. BTW, I am using `ERC721Enumerable` in my contract which conflicts with `ERC721Burnable`, but I can also see that `_burn` is a built-in function inside ERC721. Maybe I can just copy that function inside `ERC721Burnable` into my smart contract to make it work?

Comment: @TerryWindwalker See the update.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried the burn function out and I see the NFT just simply disappeared.